# How can I send 1 request per 5 seconds in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to send 1 request per 5 seconds to login via api. I am not sure how it can be done via thread group.

I tried :

```
No. of threads : 100
Ramp-up period : 20
Loop-count : Forever
```

But it sends 5 requests per second.

Should I use ultimate thread group for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) is what you're looking for. Add it as a child of your request and configure it as follows:

- Target Throughput: `12`
- Calculate Throughput Based On: `all active threads in current thread group`

[image: JMeter Constant Throughput Timer]

This will limit the rate of requests execution to 12 requests per minute (1 request in 5 seconds)

Also be aware of enhanced version: [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps.

Comment: If I use constant timer then what should be my ramp up time?

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
No. of threads : 100
Ramp-up period : 500
```

It would send 100 requests in 500 seconds. that is 1 request per 5 seconds.